# How we prevent second person login when already first person is logged in same

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security, ionic-framework

I have a requirement that only one user is active state(i.e. login) and other user can't be login using same credentials.when he is trying to login i need to restrict other one using Ionic+AngularJs(Hybrid) mobile app.

Currently am using Servers side as Java and Client side as Hybrid framework.
and when a user login it generated a Basic authentication token and after thert for every REST API service calls am sending generated token as

```
 login: function(userName, password, authTokenValue) {

        var loginPath = '/login/' + userName + '/' + password;
        //calling  loginCustomer rest service
        return $resource(host + loginPath, {}, {

            query: {
                headers: {

                    'X-Auth-Token': authTokenValue
                },
                method: 'GET'
            }
        });
    }
```

and Token is generates based on userName and password  it is not identical (i.e. randomly generated token value )
but i am not maintaining any session for any Users but i have an requirement that when user is already login another person can't access those service using same credentials.

please provide some guidelines how can i achive it?
sorry for my bad English

Comment: actually i don't know is there any method to do that using inbuild function. if i have to do that, ill do like this. save his last logged IP,login time and  logout time and compare it when next user login.

Comment: Probably you're looking for concurrent session control: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-concurrent-sessions

Comment: @SlavaSemushin I used that same concept in my server side. **but first user in login (active) and next user login with same credentials then second user become active and first user become inactive mode**

Comment: Yes, that how it works by default. Now you need to find a way how to override/customize this logic and modify it to do opposite things.

Comment: Not really related to the question but it is not recommended to pass the username and password through the url.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin can you please provide some suggestion on that

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking for is session management.

Since you use tokens it might be a good idea to save the token once you authenticate (persistent storage such as `$sessionStorage` or `$localStorage` - check [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)).

When somebody else wants to perform a login you simply check these stores for a token. If none is present then that user may continue their login. Otherwise you just reject the promise with "Log out first" message.

Comment: but it's not related to single device. i want to perform on multiple device.